# Python - Using Plotly, is there a way to make text labels appear as you zoom into bubble plot?

Tags: python, plotly, zooming

Here's an example of my data:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd 

data = {'vocab':['today', 'started', 'half', 'slowly', "probably", "took", "two", "daily"], 
        'x':[-12.9, -23.4, -7.1, -6.3, -20.5, -5.8, -32.6, -8.3],
        'y':[21.6, 21.8, 33.2, 22.7, 34, 0.4, 22.4, 31.9],
        'freq':[277, 491, 264, 138, 250, 279, 753, 93]} 

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

fig = go.Figure()

config = dict({'scrollZoom': True})

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = df.x, y = df.y, 
                         mode = "markers + text", 
                         text = df['vocab'], 
                         marker = dict(
                         size = df['freq'],
                         sizemode = 'area',
                         sizeref=2.*max(df['freq'])/(295.**2))))


fig.update_layout(title = "help",
                 hovermode='closest',
                 yaxis=dict(zeroline=False, showgrid=False),
                 xaxis=dict(zeroline=False, showgrid=False),
                 showlegend = False,
                 width = 1000,
                 height = 800,
                 template = "presentation")

fig.show(config=config)
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to have the text labels appear as I zoom in, based on the frequency?

So, right when you load the plot, you might only see "two" and "started", but as you zoom in, the other labels appear.

Comment: I removed plotly.offline as sice version 4.0 plotly is offline only.

Comment: It seems to me a complicated problem. Do you want the text only when the bubble is the only one in the zoomed area? Or whenever there are not intersection? Have you consider to use some action on click?

Comment: @rpanai I've struggled to come up with a logic for it. But I really like the idea of having text appear when there isn't an intersection, as long as the highest frequency terms are appearing regardless (although maybe those could be annotations).